# How to move Firebase real-time database to localhost database

Tags: node.js, json, flask, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

For this moment I have working Vue application with firebase realtime database (communication via HTTP requests), but I need to run this application on device w/o internet access. My idea is to create node/flask server on localhost and implement request handling from Vue app and now the question is:

- Is it possible to install some no-sql databases that will work similar to firebase, so I will able to export JSON files from my existing realtime database and put it on localhost node server? Most important to me is getting access via http requests to specific branchces of json files.

For now i only created node server and looking for best solution. Best thing for me would be just replacing firebase url with some database localhost url and all logic will work the same.

Comment: I hesitate to mention this, since it is not designed for production use, but there is the [Firebase Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite), which is API compatible and runs completely locally.

Comment: yea I saw this, could you please clear the thought that is not designed for production use? I think I will try this emulator, but this application is for commercial use, maybe some stupid question, but will be legal to use this emulator in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no option to run a self-hosted production-ready version of the Firebase Realtime Database.

The closest equivalent (as user 9072997 [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71752760/how-to-move-firebase-real-time-database-to-localhost-database#comment126803418_71752760)) is the [Firebase Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite), which you can run locally and supports the Realtime Database, but is explicitly intended for:

> Local development with Local Emulator Suite can be a good fit for your prototyping, development and continuous integration workflows.

Comment: thanks for the answer! as I asked user 9072997 is this Firebase Emulator free for use for commercial purposes? And maybe you know the most significant differences between emulator and realtime database?

Comment: The intended use-case for the emulators is for development and testing. There is no definite list of differences between the emulated RTDB and the hosted servers, as that'd be a moving target: the engineers working on the emulators add features as they are needed for the documented use-case.